# Clone table row but not first td - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having some problem using the clone function in jQuery. I have been able to clone the table header (first row). But I also need to remove the first element from the row (th), I have tried quite a few things but keep failing, here is one of my attempts:

```
$('.teamStatusTable tr:first:not("th:first-child")').clone().prependTo($('#tableTrackActual'));
```

Does anyone know a method that works ?

Comment: So you need to copy everything except the first element from the first row, and then remove everything except the first element from the first row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're cloning the entire tr, then it'll include all of its children. You can clone the element and then `remove()` the offending element element.

```
$('.teamStatusTable tr:first').clone().prependTo(...).find('th:first-child').remove();
```

Comment: You rock dude ! don't y I did't try that - must be getting to the end of day lol.