# Clone a <table> with particular rows and columns

Tags: jquery

I am struggling to get the following functionality working, I need to clone a table, but I only need the first `'td'` from each row and remove the header. Can anyone point me in the right direction I have tried a few things now but no joy. Tried a few things such as :

```
$('#tableMembers').find('tr').find('td:not(first)').remove();
```

Which obviously didn't work.

Comment: Did you try the ideas exposed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206746/clone-table-row-but-not-first-td-jquery ?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should clone first, otherwise you are removing from the original.

```
var newTable$ = $('#tableMembers').clone().find('tr').find('td:gt(0)').remove();
$('#someTargetLocation').append(newTable$);
```

Something along those lines should do it. td:gt(0) will find all td elements that are not the first in their row.

Without the find('tr'), all cells after the first one in the first row are removed, because the td:gt(0) takes it's context as the table. With the find('tr') filter in place, the find('td:gt(0)') filter takes each tr as its individual context and the first cell of each row is retained.

Comment: I'll give something like that a go tried this:$('.teamStatusTable').find('tr').find('td:first').prependTo($('#tableMembers'));

Comment: however i still need to maintain the actual rows so the results are displayed correctly

Comment: Your example in the first comment will move the cells from the  original table to the new location. You need to call clone() to copy them.

Comment: I am trying to clone #teamStatusTable and move it to #teamMembers - however i have to remove the thead which i can do after the append - i have the functionality working using $('.teamStatusTable').find('tr').find('td:first').remove($('#tableMembers')); however i need the copied 'td's to be wraped in rows - any ideas ?

Comment: You need to clarify. In jQuery, the term clone is very specific. It means you take a copy of the original, and then leave the original alone. You then do something with the copy. I think that what you are actually wanting to do is move some elements from one place to another. But it is not clear what you are trying to do. Please update your question with a desired before and after markup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working sample.

```
$('#tableMembers').clone().prependTo(....).find('td:first-child').remove();
```

[**updated running code**](http://jsfiddle.net/mphH4/1/)

Comment: This does the opposite of what the OP is trying to do. He is trying to remove everything except for the first cells.